# Removing quote from a element in a List using Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am using

```
I/P 
atomic_list_concat(M,' ',"cal 1 2").
O/P
[cal, '1', '2']
```

However i need the list as [cal,1,2] how do i achieve this in prolog?

Comment: Hint: `?- atom_number('1', N).`.